# oracle pl/sql function name resolution error

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, namespaces

I am trying to perform a fairly simple function. I want to pass in an hostname to this function, i want it to take that hostname and use it to find the systemID associated with that hostname and return it.

below you will see that i have a pl/sql block that is calling a function called `GET_SYSTEMID` when i pass in a varchar to this function i get an error back. when i hard code the same string inside the function i get the correct results back. The column holding the hostnames has a unique constraint so if i am using the exact hostname of one of my servers (i am for sure) there should only be one matching row.

This is my calling block:

```
Declare
    sysid number;
Begin
    sysid := Server.GET_SYSTEMID('MyHost');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SYSID is '||sysid);    
END;
```

If i use that block to call this function it does not work:

```
FUNCTION GET_SYSTEMID(Hostname varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    SysID number;
BEGIN 
    SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
    INTO SysID
    FROM mySystems
    where mySystems.HOSTNAME = Hostname;

    return SysID;
END GET_SYSTEMID;
```

When i run the above i get this error message:

```
Declare
    sysid number;
Begin
    sysid := Server.GET_SYSTEMID('MyHost');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SYSID is '||sysid);    
END;
Error at line 3
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "MySchema.Server", line 33
ORA-06512: at line 12
```

These next two do work but as they hard code the hostname they dont do what i need this function to do:

Number one:

```
FUNCTION GET_SYSTEMID(Hostname varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
    SysID number;
    tmp varchar2(8) := 'MyHost';--should be identical to passed in value
BEGIN 
    SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
    INTO SysID
    FROM mySystems
    where mySystems.HOSTNAME = tmp;

    return SysID;
END GET_SYSTEMID;
```

Number Two:

```
FUNCTION GET_SYSTEMID(Hostname varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    SysID number;
BEGIN 

    SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
    INTO SysID
    FROM mySystems
    where mySystems.HOSTNAME = 'MyHost';--should be identical to passed in value

    return SysID;
END GET_SYSTEMID;
```

Comment: Probably, name collision.  Try to rename the parameter: `FUNCTION GET_SYSTEMID(p_Hostname varchar2)`

Comment: As Egor says, `mySystems.HOSTNAME = Hostname` is like `1=1`, so all rows are returned! The SQL is _NOT_ case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of name resolution.

When you have a parameter `hostname` and a `hostname` column in the table that you're referencing, the scope resolution rules cause most people confusion.  That's why many people recommend using a naming convention for parameters and local variables that differentiates them from table names.  In my code, for example, I use `p_` to prefix parameter names and `l_` to prefix local variables.

In your code, when you have

```
SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
INTO SysID
FROM mySystems
where mySystems.HOSTNAME = Hostname;
```

`hostname` is resolved as the column in the table, not the parameter.  This causes the query to return every row in the table where `hostname` is not null which causes the error.  You can explicitly prefix the parameter name with the function name to force `hostname` to resolve to the parameter

```
SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
INTO SysID
FROM mySystems
where mySystems.HOSTNAME = GET_SYSTEMID.Hostname;
```

That works.  But adding the function name prefix generally gets annoying.  If you adopt the convention of prefixing parameter names and local variable names, you'd get something like

```
FUNCTION GET_SYSTEMID(p_hostname varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    l_sysID number;
BEGIN 
    SELECT mySystems.SYSTEMID
    INTO l_sysID
    FROM mySystems
    where mySystems.HOSTNAME = p_hostname;

    return l_sysID;
END GET_SYSTEMID;
```

That also works and tends (in my mind) to be clearer than adding explicit function name prefixes all over the place.

Comment: This answer is correct and very well written. thanks @justin for explaining what i am surprised i hadnt ran into after all this time teaching myself pl/sql. Thanks again